# Create variant alternating value and array of value

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to have something like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
using make_variant_t = /* ??? */;
```

such that, for instance, `make_variant_t<Foo, Bar>` evaluates as the type

```
 std::variant<Foo, std::vector<Foo>, Bar, std::vector<Bar>>
```

*in that order*. How, if it is possible, can this be achieved?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by this. Why can't you write it out directly? And what does this have to do with variadic templates?

Comment: @NicolBolas I assume OP has somewhere a variadic pack containing `Foo, Bar, ...` and wants to expand it as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution with `std::tuple` under the hood:

```
namespace impl {
    template<class> struct tuple_to_variant;

    template<class... Ts>
    struct tuple_to_variant<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
        using type = std::variant<Ts...>;
    };
}

template<class... Ts>
using make_variant_t = typename impl::tuple_to_variant<decltype(    
    std::tuple_cat(std::declval<std::tuple<Ts, std::vector<Ts>>>()...))>::type;
```

Comment: This answer is much cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
namespace impl
{
    template <typename R, typename ...P>
    struct make_variant {};

    template <typename ...R, typename P0, typename ...P>
    struct make_variant<std::variant<R...>, P0, P...>
    {
        using type = typename make_variant<std::variant<R..., P0, std::vector<P0>>, P...>::type;
    };

    template <typename ...R>
    struct make_variant<std::variant<R...>>
    {
        using type = std::variant<R...>;
    };
}

template <typename ...P>
using make_variant_t = typename impl::make_variant<std::variant<>, P...>::type;
```

Now, `make_variant_t<Foo, Bar>` should expand to `std::variant<Foo, std::vector<Foo>, Bar, std::vector<Bar>>`.

Comment: @Quentin ... >:3

Comment: You could replace that `type_list` with a `std::variant` to avoid having an extra type only for storing a list of type.

Comment: @Holt I was under impression that it's going to give me some extra instantinations of `std::variant`, which I wanted to avoid. But apparently it doesn't happen, so I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) this is a short, one-liner (as always):

```
template <typename... Ts>
using make_variant_t = mp_append<variant<Ts, vector<Ts>>...>;
```

`make_variant_t<int, char>` will first produce two variants, `variant<int, vector<int>>` and `variant<char, vector<char>>`. Those each are "lists" in the Mp11 sense, and `mp_append` takes a bunch of lists and concatenates them together, producing `variant<int, vector<int>, char, vector<char>>` as desired. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/JafsS_).

Comment: Unrelated question: is there a chance to get something like this in the standard library in the near future?

Comment: @Evg No. Peter [proposed it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0949r0.html), but SG7 wants to go a different route with compile time programming and want to have a good foundation for what they want it to look like before adding more compile time programming facilities. Until then, Boost.Mp11 is awesome.